# Operator priority on overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-precedence

I am trying to make a C++ compiled model for simple SQL commands. For example this could be a part of my main function which i must be able to handle :

```
CREATE_TABLE(books) [             // create("books");ovr[
    COLUMN(c1) TYPE(string),      // "title string",
    COLUMN(c2) TYPE(string),      // "author string",
    COLUMN(num1) TYPE(int)        // "price int"
                    ];
```

So in order to do that i had to overload the "[]" and "," operators. After doing so, I figured out that the "," overloader is executed before the "[]" one. Whereas my guess would be that "[]" should be executed first. Is there any particular reason why this happens? Or is it simply because the "[]" is executed when "]" is found?

Comment: 1. This sounds like a horrible (and doomed-to-fail) idea. 2. Think about it: How could the indexing possibly happen before the expression inside the brackets is evaluated and yields the index?

Comment: yes youre right but (im new in c++) i had to make sure it just didn't happen by chance... I wanted to make sure that was the case thx!

Comment: If you want to play with this type of things, take a look at the boost::proto library. There were some articles in [cpp-next.com](http://cpp-next.com) from Eric Nibler ( [Expressive-C++](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2010/08/expressive-c-introduction/) ) with a tutorial of shorts in how to implement DSELs with that library.

Comment: Thank you i will have a look at this :)

Comment: I'm still trying to work out what `COLUMN` and `TYPE` will be to make that work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expression would be compiled to something like the following, which might explain the evaluation order:

```
CREATE_TABLE(books).operator[](
    COLUMN(c1) TYPE(string).operator,(
        COLUMN(c2) TYPE(string).operator,(
            COLUMN(num1) TYPE(int) 
        )
    )
);
```

or

```
CREATE_TABLE(books).operator[](
    operator,( COLUMN(c1) TYPE(string), 
        operator,( COLUMN(c2) TYPE(string), COLUMN(num1) TYPE(int))
    )
);
```

depending on how your `operator,()` is defined (and maybe how the `COLUMN` and `TYPE` macros are defined).

Answer (score 3):

The expression inside the `[]` has to be evaluated first - it needs to be passed in as the argument, which is why you see the `operator,` being called first.

Answer (score 2):

Because in order to call `operator[]`, it needs a single parameter. It treats what's inside the brackets as an expression with commas, and uses `operator,` to get a single result with which to call your `operator[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `[]` operator takes a single argument, it waits for the entire expression between the `[]` to be evaluated before it is evaluated itself.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the result of `operator,()` as the argument of `operatot[]()`, so it's only logical that the former is evaluated first, as in `f(g(x))`.

Also, nothing is "parsed" at runtime. C++ is a *compiled* language.